# question about struct and pointers

Tags: c++, bit-fields

let us consider following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef struct bf_{
    unsigned x:4;
    unsigned y:4;
    unsigned z:4;
    unsigned  w:4;
    }bf;
int main(){
    unsigned short i=8;
    unsigned short j=9;
    bf* bitfields=(bf *)&i;
    bf*bit=(bf*)&j;
    bitfields->w=12;
    printf("%d\n",bitfields->x);
    printf("%d\n",bit->y);
    printf("%d\n",bitfields->w);



     return 0;
}
```

this fragment

```
unsigned short j=9;
bf*bit=(bf*)&j;
printf("%d\n",bit->y);
```

i have  add after guess some interesting characteristic of this code  for example
 after this   place

```
bf* bitfields=(bf *)&i;
```

when we write `printf("%d\n",bitfields->x);` which prints  8 i understand that    using pointers and references value of i will be granted to x and  so it prints 8   for instance when we write `bitfiled->y` it writes 0 so i decided to introduce second element variable j create new instance of bf structer and    make reference of j  after which 
statement bit->y should write 9 because  as i understand it is order definition  but it gives me 0  why? please explain  me how this code works?i am not english speaker so please sorry for my bad english

Comment: `typedef struct`... how very '80s of you!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there are no references used in this code. The `&` character, when used as a unary operator (instead of as part of a type name), as in this context, means "address-of". So `&i` is "the address of `i`", **not** "a reference to `i`".

I'm not sure where you're getting the idea that using the value 9 as your `bf` struct should cause `y` to get the value `9`. When you write this:

```
bf* bitfields=(bf *)&i;
```

What happens is that you are telling the compiler "treat the value at memory location `&i` as if it were a `bf` structure". The `bf` structure is defined so that, starting from the least significant (right-most) bits, the first four bits are the `x` value, the second four bits are the `y` value, the third four bits are the `z` value, etc.

So since the value at the location `&i` is `8`, and 8 in 16-bit binary is

```
0000 0000 0000 1000
```

The fields of `bitfields` are going to be:

```
0000 0000 0000 1000 
  w    z    y    x
```

So the value of `x` (a 4-bit unsigned integer) is 8, while the values of `y`, `z`, and `w` are 0.

In the case where you write

```
bf*bit=(bf*)&j;
```

you are doing the same thing as above, except now the value is 9, so the assignments are:

```
0000 0000 0000 1001 
  w    z    y    x
```

So `x` has the value 9, and the other values are still 0.

If you want to assign the value 9 to `y` instead of `x`, the assignments would need to look like this:

```
0000 0000 1001 0000 
  w    z    y    x
```

So the value you would have to use is the value with the 16-bit binary representation

```
0000 0000 1001 0000
```

Which is 144. So if you let `j = 144` instead of `j = 9`, you would observe that `bit->y` is 9, and all of the other fields in `bit` are 0.

Comment: Is the order of `x y z w` reversed because of how the struct is stored in memory or because of how the short is stored?

Comment: @Kyle Technically, the whole thing is implementation-defined. I've inferred from his example that the `x` field is being assigned to the least-significant 4-bits, so I'm assuming that the compiler has chosen to lay out the bitfields in order of least-significant to most-significant bits. They appear "reversed" in my figures because in English, numbers are written in the opposite order, with the most-significant digits first.

Comment: Cool, it just has to do with the endianness then.

Comment: 0x0090 != 72.  9 * 16 = 144.  But the C++ language makes few guarantees about the layout of bitfields.

Comment: @Ben right you are. I had simply been lazy and typed "0b1001000 in decimal" into Google, and you'll note that I missed a 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the packing that occurs when the struct or class is compiled.
See these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx#vclrfhowalignworkswithdatapacking.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28VS.80%29.aspx

By default, the size of a struct at compile time, is *not* the same as the total size of it's members.

Comment: Bitfields generally get packed in this scenario.  On most implementations, the compiler will refuse to let a bitfield cross an alignment boundary determined by the underlying type (which here is `unsigned int`), but that wouldn't come into play here.